# How do you keep a tracklay session tidy?

Tags: editing, post-production, processing, clean

I recently went to an open door event at a local post production house. They showed us their workflow and how they get things done quickly.

They showed us their tracklay session. All the ambiences, effects and foley all neatly placed along the time line ready for a mix session. Barely any plug-ins/processors.

I find that my sessions get a lot messier than this as I also do a lot of editing in my tracklaying process. Most of the sounds I get might need filtering, EQ'ing or some other process to tweak them for the intended purpose. The problem is I end up with separate tracks for many of the sounds as they're all being processed differently.

How do other people work neater than this? Do people tailor their sounds in a previous session before tracklaying? I try to automate a processor so I can tweak the parameters for different sound along the same track but this can get messy.

Thanks

Comment: quick comment - I'd just say 'it depends'. 2 days to do the job, 142 channels is easier [or just a damn sight quicker & less automation to run around after]. 6 weeks & up, get everything lined up beforehand & lay it out neatly. Use sub-mixes, pre-prep FX etc. Keep your originals tagged with the same codes you use for your tracks, in case you need to go back & tweak/re-import.